# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object referenceProfileFragment.java:43)

Tags: php, android, sharedpreferences

Here is my Share Preference Manager

```js
package com.example.call_for_help.storage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import com.example.call_for_help.models.Helper;
import com.example.call_for_help.models.Requestor;

public class SharedPrefManager {
    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME="my_shared_preff";
    private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
    private Context mcCtx;

    private SharedPrefManager(Context mcCtx){
        this.mcCtx=mcCtx;
    }
    public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getIntance(Context mCtx){
        if(mInstance==null){
            mInstance=new SharedPrefManager(mCtx);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    //User uses the class of User and "user" is the object so it can access to the function and use User's model
    public void savehelper(Helper helper){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mcCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("id",helper.getHelper_id());
        editor.putFloat("rating",helper.getHelper_rating());
        editor.putString("student_id",helper.getHelper_student_id());
        editor.putString("name",helper.getHelper_name());
        editor.putString("email",helper.getHelper_email());
        editor.putString("phone",helper.getHelper_phone());
        editor.putString("gender",helper.getHelper_gender());
        editor.putString("category",helper.getHelper_category());
        editor.putString("description",helper.getHelper_description());
        editor.apply();
        editor.commit();
    }


    public void saverequestor(Requestor requestor){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mcCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("id",requestor.getRequestor_id());
        editor.putString("student_id",requestor.getRequestor_student_id());
        editor.putString("name",requestor.getRequestor_name());
        editor.putString("email",requestor.getRequestor_email());
        editor.putString("phone",requestor.getRequestor_phone());
        editor.putString("gender",requestor.getRequestor_gender());
        editor.apply();
        editor.commit();

    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mcCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //if id=="1" means not login (false)
        //if id!="-1" means logged in (true)
        return sharedPreferences.getInt("id",-1)!=-1;
    }

    public Helper getHelper(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mcCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return new Helper(
                sharedPreferences.getInt("id",-1),
                sharedPreferences.getFloat("rating",0),
                sharedPreferences.getString("student_id",null),
                sharedPreferences.getString("name",null),
                sharedPreferences.getString("email",null),
                sharedPreferences.getString("phone",null),
                sharedPreferences.getString("gender",null),
                sharedPreferences.getString("category",null),
                sharedPreferences.getString("description",null)
        );
    }

    public Requestor getRequestor(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mcCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return new Requestor(
                sharedPreferences.getInt("id",-1),
                sharedPreferences.getString("student_id",null),
                sharedPreferences.getString("name",null),
                sharedPreferences.getString("email",null),
                sharedPreferences.getString("phone",null),
                sharedPreferences.getString("gender",null)
                );
    }

    public void clear(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mcCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Here is my Login Function, The login function worked I can validate my student_id and student_password but The Shared Pref Manager seems not saving the response data

```js
package com.example.call_for_help.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.call_for_help.R;
import com.example.call_for_help.api.RetrofitClient;
import com.example.call_for_help.helper_activities.HelperActivity;
import com.example.call_for_help.models.Helper;
import com.example.call_for_help.models.HelperResponse;
import com.example.call_for_help.models.RequestorResponse;
import com.example.call_for_help.storage.SharedPrefManager;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText editTextStudentId;
    private EditText editTextStudentPassword;
    private Button buttonLogin;
    private TextView textViewSignUp;
    private RadioGroup radioGroupUserType;
    private RadioButton radioButtonHelper;
    private RadioButton radioButtonRequestor;
    private TextView textViewMessage;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editTextStudentId=findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentId);
        editTextStudentPassword=findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentPassword);
        buttonLogin=findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        textViewSignUp=findViewById(R.id.textViewSignUp);
        radioButtonHelper=findViewById(R.id.radioButtonHelper);
        radioButtonRequestor=findViewById(R.id.radioButtonRequestor);
        radioGroupUserType=findViewById(R.id.radioGroupUserType);
        textViewMessage=findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);

        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        textViewSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
        radioButtonHelper.setOnClickListener(this);
        radioButtonRequestor.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    private void helperLogin(){
        String student_id=editTextStudentId.getText().toString().trim();
        String student_password=editTextStudentPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if(student_id.isEmpty()){
            editTextStudentId.setError("Student ID is required");
            editTextStudentId.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(student_password.isEmpty()){
            editTextStudentPassword.setError("Plese fill up your password");
            editTextStudentPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(student_password.length()<6){
            editTextStudentPassword.setError("Password length should be at least 6");
            editTextStudentPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }



        Call<HelperResponse> call=RetrofitClient
                .getInstance().getApi().helperLogin(student_id,student_password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<HelperResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<HelperResponse> call, Response<HelperResponse> response) {
                HelperResponse helperResponse = response.body();
                if(!helperResponse.isError()){
                    SharedPrefManager.getIntance(MainActivity.this)
                            .savehelper(helperResponse.getHelper());

                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelperActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"login failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<HelperResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void requestorlogin(){
        String student_id=editTextStudentId.getText().toString().trim();
        String student_password=editTextStudentPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if(student_id.isEmpty()){
            editTextStudentId.setError("Student ID is required");
            editTextStudentId.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(student_password.isEmpty()){
            editTextStudentPassword.setError("Please fill up your password");
            editTextStudentPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(student_password.length()<6){
            editTextStudentPassword.setError("Password length should be at least 6");
            editTextStudentPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        Call<RequestorResponse> call=RetrofitClient
                .getInstance().getApi().requestorLogin(student_id,student_password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RequestorResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RequestorResponse> call, Response<RequestorResponse> response) {
                RequestorResponse requestorResponse = response.body();
                if(!requestorResponse.isError()){
                    SharedPrefManager.getIntance(MainActivity.this)
                            .saverequestor(requestorResponse.getRequestor());

                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelperActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"login failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RequestorResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });



    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonLogin:
            if(radioButtonHelper.isChecked()){
                helperLogin();
            }else if(radioButtonRequestor.isChecked()){
                requestorlogin();
            }else if(!radioButtonRequestor.isChecked() && !radioButtonHelper.isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Please Select A User Type",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                break;
            case R.id.textViewSignUp:
                startActivity(new Intent(this,SignUpActivity.class));

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my model for the shared pref Manager

```js
package com.example.call_for_help.models;

public class Helper {
    private int helper_id;
    private float helper_rating;
    private String helper_student_id,helper_name,helper_email,helper_phone,helper_gender,helper_category,helper_description;

    public Helper(int helper_id, float helper_rating, String helper_student_id, String helper_name, String helper_email, String helper_phone, String helper_gender, String helper_category, String helper_description) {
        this.helper_id = helper_id;
        this.helper_rating = helper_rating;
        this.helper_student_id = helper_student_id;
        this.helper_name = helper_name;
        this.helper_email = helper_email;
        this.helper_phone = helper_phone;
        this.helper_gender = helper_gender;
        this.helper_category = helper_category;
        this.helper_description = helper_description;
    }

    public int getHelper_id() {
        return helper_id;
    }

    public float getHelper_rating() {
        return helper_rating;
    }

    public String getHelper_student_id() {
        return helper_student_id;
    }

    public String getHelper_name() {
        return helper_name;
    }

    public String getHelper_email() {
        return helper_email;
    }

    public String getHelper_phone() {
        return helper_phone;
    }

    public String getHelper_gender() {
        return helper_gender;
    }

    public String getHelper_category() {
        return helper_category;
    }

    public String getHelper_description() {
        return helper_description;
    }
}
```

Here is my PHP

```html
$app->post('/helperlogin',function(Request $request,Response $response){
    if(!haveEmptyParameters(array('student_id','student_password'),$request,$response)){
        $request_data = $request->getParsedBody();
        $student_id = $request_data['student_id'];
        $student_password = $request_data['student_password'];
        $db=new DbOperations;
        $result=$db->studentLogin($student_id,$student_password);
        if($result==USER_AUTHENTICATED){
            $helper=$db->getHelperByStudentId($student_id);
            $response_data=array();

            $response_data['error']=false;
            $response_data['message']='Login Succesful';
            $response_data['helper']=$helper;
            $response->write(json_encode($response_data));
            return $response
                        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
                        ->withStatus(200); 
        }else if($result==USER_NOT_FOUND){
            $helper=$db->getHelperByStudentId($student_id);
            $response_data=array();

            $response_data['error']=true;
            $response_data['message']='Student not Exist';
            $response_data['helper']=$helper;
            $response->write(json_encode($response_data));
            return $response
                        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
                        ->withStatus(404); 

        }else if($result==USER_PASSWORD_DO_NOT_MATCH){
            $helper=$db->getHelperByStudentId($student_id);
            $response_data=array();

            $response_data['error']=true;
            $response_data['message']='Invalid credential';
            $response_data['helper']=$helper;
            $response->write(json_encode($response_data));
            return $response
                        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
                        ->withStatus(200); 

        }
    }

    return $response
                        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
                        ->withStatus(422); 
});

public function getHelperByStudentId($student_id){
    $stmt=$this->con->prepare("SELECT helper.id,
    (SELECT AVG(rating.rating) FROM rating WHERE rating.helper_id=helper.id)as 'helper_rating',
    (SELECT student.student_id FROM student WHERE student.student_id=helper.student_id)as 'helper_student_id',
    (SELECT student.student_name FROM student WHERE student.student_id=helper.student_id)as 'helper_name',
    (SELECT student.student_email FROM student WHERE student.student_id=helper.student_id)as 'helper_email',
    (SELECT student.student_phone FROM student WHERE student.student_id=helper.student_id)as 'helper_phone',
    (SELECT student.student_gender FROM student WHERE student.student_id=helper.student_id)as 'helper_gender',
    helper.category,helper.description FROM helper WHERE helper.student_id=? ");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$student_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($helper_id,$helper_rating,$helper_student_id,$helper_name,$helper_email,$helper_phone,$helper_gender,$helper_category,$helper_description);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $helper=array();
    $helper['helper_id']=$helper_id;
    $helper['helper_rating']=$helper_rating;
    $helper['helper_student_id']=$helper_student_id;
    $helper['helper_name']=$helper_name;
    $helper['helper_email']=$helper_email;
    $helper['helper_phone']=$helper_phone;
    $helper['helper_gender']=$helper_gender;
    $helper['helper_category']=$helper_category;
    $helper['helper_description']=$helper_description;
    return $helper;    
}
```

Here is where I call my Shared Pref Manager and where the error message pointed to

```js
package com.example.call_for_help.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.call_for_help.R;
import com.example.call_for_help.storage.SharedPrefManager;

public class HelperProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView textViewHelperId,
            textViewHelperName,
            textViewHelperRating,
            textViewHelperemail,
            textViewHelperGender,textViewhelperPhone,textViewHelperCategory,textViewHelperDescription;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_helperhome,container,false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Helper Profile");
        textViewHelperId=view.findViewById(R.id.textViewHelperId);
        textViewHelperName=view.findViewById(R.id.textViewHelperName);
        textViewHelperRating=view.findViewById(R.id.textViewHelperRating);
        textViewHelperemail=view.findViewById(R.id.textViewHelperEmail);
        textViewhelperPhone=view.findViewById(R.id.textViewHelperPhone);
        textViewHelperGender=view.findViewById(R.id.textViewHelperGender);
        textViewHelperCategory=view.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategory);
        textViewHelperDescription=view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);

        //float rating =SharedPrefManager.getIntance(getActivity()).getHelper().getHelper_rating();
        textViewHelperName.setText(SharedPrefManager.getIntance(getActivity()).getHelper().getHelper_name());



    }
}
```

I am very new to Android Studio and PHP though, It took me hours to look for the mistake but I still cant find it.

Comment: ["Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster."](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)

Comment: `Java !== JavaScript` please use related tags

Comment: Way too much code, peeps are unlikely to prod through all that. **[Read all about a minimal, complete, verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** and try to distill this to the essence of your issue. tip : when you distill it, you are likely to find the issue.

Comment: Simple solution just check that your textview is properly bind or not. Look into the line findViewById.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly paste code of "fragment_helperhome.xml" layout file. 
1.) Please make sure there is a textview with id "textViewHelperName" in that xml file as you are using it in following line:
textViewHelperName=view.findViewById(R.id.textViewHelperName);
2.) As onViewCreated() is called after onCreateView(), please make sure textViewHelperName is not used before onViewCreated() as before that it will be null.
3.) To avoid null pointer exception, add a null check.